# IE save as pop up automation using powershell

Tags: powershell

[image]

Automating a process where i download a report from a link and save it in a particular folder. I can use sendkeys to automate this but under headless condition it fails. Is there any way in powershell to automate this.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to download a file via Powershell. You'll need to know a direct link to it, then you can automate it via this script:

```
$url = "http://your-site/report.xlsx"
$output = "$PSScriptRoot\report.xlsx"

$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.DownloadFile($url, $output)
```

There are other options how to download the file via Powershell, but this is the best tradeoff for you.

Comment: The real issue would be the report link, Its an asp website which creates the link on the fly when i click a button. Is there any way i can know the report uri from the source.

Comment: Yes, you can programmatically send a POST request to imitate button press.